# Прозрачность jPanel и jLabel

Tags: java

Хочу сделать прозрачность для `jPanel` делаю это с помощью

`jPanel1.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 30));`

Все хорошо, панель полу прозрачная, надписи на панельке тоже прозрачные, но когда начинаю делать `setText` на jLabel, выходят баги, надпись на надпись накладывается и прозрачность надписи начинает белеть.

В интернете прочитал об `jPanel1.setOpaque(false);`

Сделал, все работает как надо, но панель стала полностью прозрачная как это исправить?

`JDK1.7-1.8 NetBeans javax.swing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если переопределить у `JPanel` метод `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, поставить точку остановки и пройти вглубь по шагам, то будет видно, что панель просто заполняет все свое пространство цветом `getBackground()`, если `isOpaque()` возвращает `true`. Если панель прозрачная, то ее `paintComponent` не делает ничего. А без установки прозрачности Swing не будет перерисовывать компоненты, лежащие ниже панели, что вызовет разные интересные эффекты.

Вам нужно переопределить `paintComponent` у полупрозрачной панели (создать полноценный класс-наследник, или анонимный класс) и сделать заливку с нужной прозрачностью.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    // Полосатая фоновая панель
    final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() ) {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent( g );
            g.setColor( Color.RED );
            for ( int i = 0; i < getWidth(); i += 20 ) {
                g.fillRect( i, 0, 10, getHeight() );
            }
        }
    };
    contentPane.setBackground( Color.GREEN );
    frame.setContentPane( contentPane );

    contentPane.add( new JLabel( "NORTH"), BorderLayout.NORTH );
    contentPane.add( new JLabel( "SOUTH"), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    contentPane.add( new JLabel( "EAST"), BorderLayout.EAST );
    contentPane.add( new JLabel( "WEST"), BorderLayout.WEST );

    //Полупрозрачная панель
    JPanel otherPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() ) {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
            super.paintComponent( g );

            // Apply our own painting effect
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            // 50% transparent Alpha
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));

            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    };
    otherPanel.setOpaque( false );
    contentPane.add( otherPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    // обратите внимание, что альфа-канал цвета - 255 (непрозрачный)
    // т.к. используется композит в paintComponent
    // можно сделать полупрозрачный цвет и убрать композит
    otherPanel.setBackground( new Color( 0, 0, 250, 255 ) );

    final JLabel label = new JLabel( "LABEL" );

    otherPanel.add( label );
    label.setForeground( new Color( 200, 200, 0, 200 ) );

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible( true );

    // изменяем метку
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
                label.setText( label.getText() + " + ");
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000 );

}
```

Код перерисовки взял в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705029).

Comment: А можно покороче, глаза разбегаются среди jLabelов и других

Comment: Класс спасибо!, оказалось даже еще проще, в netbeans есть штучки, типо код вместо создания, втавил туда ваш, пеопределилось все ок, добавил пару действий и панель полу прозрачная и без багово, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Ну собственно `setOpaque(false)` делает компонент полностью прозрачным.

UPD. Попробуйте поиграться изменив непосредственно [цвет текста](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966363/1159507) на jLabel или с методом `setForeground()` вместо цвета jPanel.

Comment: Так как исправить это " выходят баги, надпись на надпись накладывается и прозрачность надписи начинает белеть" когда я делаю на надпись setText

Comment: Когда 2 полупрозрачных компонента накладываются друг на друга они меняют цвет, это неизбежно.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров обновил ответ

Comment: Тут не цвет текста меняется, а фон jLabel, Границы его

Comment: jLabel setForeground тоже не помогает, но както странно setOpaque работает на отлично, а это не хочет