# Как повесить над Jpanel ещё одну полупрозрачную JPanel?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gui

Здравствуйте. Есть одно окно java GUI-FORM (файлы .java и .form). У этого окна есть rootpanel, на который добавлены необходимые SWING-элементы. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку rootpanel'а поверх него появлялось темное полупрозрачное окно (другой overpanel) с необходимыми элементами, которые будут заданы позже. Пробовал использовать LayoutManager overlay = new OverlayLayout(JPanel rootpanel); и JLayeredPane, но для них, как понял, нужно эти 2 разноуровневых JPanel вложить в rootpanel, а он у меня уже занят SWING-элементами. Вопрос: можно ли как-то просто поместить над rootpanel overpanel без использования третьего JPanel в качестве контейнера. Надеюсь, понятно выразился. Если можно, пожалуйста, проиллюстрируйте ответ простейшим примером с кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, но можете попробовать переопределить `paintComponent` у той панели, которая должна быть прозрачной (для неё лучше, конечно, создать свой отдельный класс)

```
    //Полупрозрачная панель
    JPanel otherPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() ) {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
            super.paintComponent( g );
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                                                               //0.5f = 50% прозрачность
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f)); 

            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    };
```

Пример взял отсюда: [Прозрачность jPanel и jLabel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461729/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-jpanel-%D0%B8-jlabel)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. По поводу прозрачности с вашей помощью разобрался.