# Java. Прозрачность формы. @Override

Tags: java, swing

Новый вопрос. Есть появляющаяся форма (на ней элементы), задача сделать ее полупрозрачной. Вначале делал обычными настройками:

```
rootPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 223));
```

Прозрачность появляется, но с ней и разные артефакты (например черный непрозрачный фон под JTextField).
Нашел вот этот ответ: [Прозрачность jPanel и jLabel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461729/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-jpanel-%D0%B8-jlabel)

Это должно помочь. Только в примере:

```
JPanel otherPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() ) {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
```

Создается новая панель и она переопределяется.
У меня панель уже создана "rootPanel" и на ней располагаются объекты, поэтому я не могу ее удалить и создать новую. Собственно вопрос как переопределить уже существующую панель, или может есть еще какой-то способ сделать прозрачность?

Весь класс выглядит так:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Profile {

    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JPanel iconAvaPanel;
    private JTextField nameTextField;
    private JTextField familyNameTextField;
    private JButton Button;
    private JTextPane TextPane;
    private JButton buttonClose;
    private JLabel buttonExit;
    private JLabel phoneNumber;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel panel;

    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
        mainPanel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                // Apply our own painting effect
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                // 50% transparent Alpha
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));

                g2d.setColor(getBackground());
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());


                g2d.dispose();


            }
        };
        mainPanel.setOpaque( false );
        mainPanel.setBackground( new Color( 0, 0, 0, 200 ) );
        mainPanel.setVisible(false);
        mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    }




    public Profile() {

        nameTextField.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        familyNameTextField.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

        buttonExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mousePressed(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }



    public JTextField getNameTextField() {
        return nameTextField;
    }

    public void setNameTextField(String name) {
        this.nameTextField.setText(name);
    }

    public JTextField getFamilyNameTextField() {
        return familyNameTextField;
    }

    public void setFamilyNameTextField(String familyName) {
        this.familyNameTextField.setText(familyName);
    }

    public JPanel getRootPanel() {
        return rootPanel;
    }

    public JButton getButtonClose()
    {
        return buttonClose;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }


}
```

Comment: Можно в начало paintComponent добавить super.paintComponent(g);

Comment: Дополню вопрос - наверное я не совсем корректно выразился. Дело в том что если (как в примере выше по ссылке) записать: JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel()...  далее расширить как в примере. То он создается, он полупрозрачный все супер, но это новая панель она пустая и становится последней на форме. А я уже в "конструкторе форм" или как это называется создал все элементы интерфейса. и он мне сам написал private JPanel rootPanel; - вот эту панель мне и надо расширить. если тупо стереть эту стоку и вписать JPanel rootPanel= new JPanel()... - то он отказывается быть прозрачным.

Comment: Этот ваш "конструктор форм" создает элементы и добавляет их в `JPanel` в конструкторе класса, реализующего `JFrame`. Вам достаточно отнаследоваться от этого класса и вызвать в конструкторе конструктор родителя(`super(параметры_конструктора_родителя)`), а затем можете добавлять все, что пожелаете

Comment: Еще бы понять как это сделать ) - весь день мучаюсь нагуглил такую штуку: в настройках JPanel поставил галочку Custom Create и туда вписал:

Comment: '    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
        mainPanel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));

                g2d.setColor(getBackground());
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        };'

Comment: Потом туда же добавил в конец: 'mainPanel.setOpaque( false );
        mainPanel.setBackground( new Color( 0, 0, 0, 200 ) );
        mainPanel.setVisible(false);
        mainPanel.setVisible(true);' И он не применяет эти параметры к моей mainPanel. Она по прежнему дефолтного цвета. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Подождите, а что вам мешает просто добавить код из их `paintComponent` в свой?

Comment: Видимо не знание как это сделать. А можно без расширения JPanel это проделать?

Comment: Приведите свою реализацию JFrame.

Comment: Добавил весь класс этой формы в вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
  panel.setOpaque( false );
```